# Como adicionar offset em array para envio de newsletter?

Tags: php

Tenho de enviar uma newsletter para todos os usuários da rede. O problema é que o *array*, contendo o resultado da consulta, possui cerca de oito mil registros. Como eu posso otimizá-lo para que não estoure o limite de memória? Adicionar `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` não foi suficiente.

```
function enviarNewsletterUsuarios(){
    $usuarios = getUsuarios();


if(!empty($usuarios) OR !isset($usuarios)){


    foreach ($usuarios as $usuario) {


        $objetivo   = getObjetivo($usuario->guid);
        $ideias     = getIdeiaPorObjetivo($objetivo, $usuario->cidade);


        $mail = new PHPMailer;


        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = 'host';                 // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = 'user';              // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = 'pass';           // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted


        $mail->From = 'teste';
        $mail->FromName = 'teste';


        $mail->addAddress($usuario->email);  // Add a recipient


        $mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML


        $mail->Subject = 'Newsletter';
        $mail->Body = utf8_decode('tesste'); 


        if(!$mail->send()) {
            echo "Ocorreu um erro ao enviar!";
            //echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            echo 'Newsletter enviado com sucesso!';
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Como está seu `getUsuarios()`? talvez a solução esteja ali. Você precisaria retornar os usuários aos poucos, seja individualmente ou em blocos, assim a leitura no banco de dados carregaria menos informações. Individualmente seria mais fácil de tratar mas perderia performance.

Comment: A função é apenas um alias para elgg_list_entities() do framework Elgg http://reference.elgg.org/entities_8php.html#af085c8362e49c4f52d4f1fcf58ca6fb8

Comment: Esta informação é muito relevante. E aí vou ficar te devendo porque não conheço nada deste *framework*. Espero que ele use `yield`. De qualquer forma, se está carregando tudo, a culpa pelo alto consumo é desta função. Não saberia dizer como resolver um problema de algo externo que eu não conheço. Claro que poderia aconselhar acessar os dados de outra forma, mas provavelmente não é o que você quer.

Comment: Ainda estou estudando o Framework e não terei como te dizer sobre isso. Se você tiver alguma ideia, agradeço por compartilha-la.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando se fala em enviar newsletters, 8 Mil destinatários não é um número elevado, muito menos um número que vá consumir toda a memória disponível.

O que parece estar a falta é uma optimização dos objectos em uso de forma a não encher a memória com a mesma informação repetida 8 Mil vezes.

## Possível optimização

```
function enviarNewsletterUsuarios() {

    // recolher os destinatários
    $usuarios = getUsuarios();

    // se temos destinatários
    if ($usuarios) {

        /* Preparar o envio definindo os valores comuns
         */
        $mail = new PHPMailer;

        $mail->isSMTP();                // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = 'host';           // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;         // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = 'user';       // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = 'pass';       // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';      // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

        $mail->From = 'teste';
        $mail->FromName = 'teste';

        $mail->WordWrap = 50;           // Set word wrap to 50 characters
        $mail->isHTML(true);            // Set email format to HTML

        $mail->Subject = 'Newsletter';
        $mail->Body = utf8_decode('tesste');


        /* Por cada destinatário enviar o email
         */
        foreach ($usuarios as $usuario) {

            $mail->addAddress($usuario->email);  // Add a recipient

            if ($mail->send()) {
                // acção quando correu bem
            } else {
                // correu mal :(
            }

            /* Limpa a lista de destinatários para evitar que o email
             * a enviar vá acumulando destinatários
             */
            $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

---

No teu código reparei também que tens:

```
$objetivo = getObjetivo($usuario->guid);
$ideias   = getIdeiaPorObjetivo($objetivo, $usuario->cidade);
```

No caso de ser algo que vai ser "injectado" no corpo do email ou no assunto do mesmo, já recomendo uma *queue* de envio em base de dados pois o trabalho de enviar o email é isso mesmo, enviar o email. A informação do mesmo deve estar preparada e pronta a utilizar ou efectivamente enfrentas problemas de consumos elevados de memória.

#### Exemplo de uma tabela para *queue* de newsletters:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `newsletter_queue` (
  `id` int(13) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Internal ID',
  `newsletter_id` int(13) NOT NULL COMMENT 'ID from the table "newsletter"',
  `entity_id` int(13) NOT NULL COMMENT 'ID from the table "entity".',
  `entity_type` enum('entity','subscriber','admin user','unknown') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'entity' COMMENT 'The entity type for statistics.',
  `send_method` set('mail','smtp') NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Message is sent using PHP mail() or SMTP.',
  `from_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Sets the From email address for the message',
  `from_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Sets the From name of the message',
  `smtp_host` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Sets the SMTP hosts. All hosts must be separated by a semicolon. You can also specify a different port for each host by using this format: [hostname:port] (e.g. "smtp1.example.com:25;smtp2.example.com"). Hosts will be tried in order.',
  `smtp_port` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '25' COMMENT 'Sets the default SMTP server port.',
  `smtp_auth` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Sets SMTP authentication. Utilizes the Username and Password variables.',
  `smtp_secure` enum('','ssl','tls','starttls') NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Sets connection prefix.',
  `smtp_username` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Sets SMTP username.',
  `smtp_password` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Sets SMTP password.',
  `recipient_mail` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `recipient_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `attachment` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `content_type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `priority` enum('1','3','5') NOT NULL DEFAULT '3' COMMENT 'Email priority (1 = High, 3 = Normal, 5 = low)',
  `charset` enum('iso-8859-1','utf-8','windows-1252') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'utf-8' COMMENT 'Sets the CharSet of the message.',
  `send_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `newsletter_id` (`newsletter_id`),
  KEY `entity_id` (`entity_id`),
  KEY `entity_type` (`entity_type`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Com uma tabela deste género, tens uma função que adiciona os emails à *queue* e a tua função de envio limitar-se-á a enviar X emails a cada X minutos. Desta forma resolves definitivamente problemas de memória agora ou no futuro quando o teu CRON é executado para enviar emails.

Comment: Isso mesmo, Zuul. O corpo do email será diferente para cada usuário dependendo de suas configurações de interesse, desse motivo fiz com que fosse criado um objeto para cada email a ser enviado. Obrigado, estou estudando as possibilidades de alteração.

Answer (score 0):

Uma coisa que você deve ter em mente é que, em termos de performance, arrays são malignos. Você nunca deve ter arrays muito grandes.

No cenário do seu problema, a coisa é pior por se tratar do envio de e-mail. Você tem algumas possíveis saídas mas num geral a idéia é basicamente trabalhar com o memso conceito de paginação de resultados.

Lista um "pouquinho", itera e envia. Diferente de uma paginação, que normalmente resgatam 10, 20 ou 50 registros, você até pode ir mais além.

Com relação a GUI, você pode fazer um *splash screen* com um *META Refresh* de X segundos que serve, inclusive para que o operador, se houver, saiba que o sistema continua funcionando.

Aqui, um fator importante seria o de ter uma forma de controlar se para aquele destinatário já foi encaminhada uma mensagem. Uma coluna no banco de dados, numa tabela de logs, de repente, é suficiente.

Isso porque a ação depende do hardware estar operando para o envio ocorrer. E se houver alguma interrupção de energia você pode ter clientes/usuários recebendo duplicatas.

Se for em lote, o que é interessante para 8 mil registros, agendar com CronJobs seria bem desejável e nada isso não seria necessário.

Porém, tudo depende do das limitações impostas pelo seu servidor. Lembre-se apenas que SPAM é crime! ;)

Comment: O envio está sendo feito automaticamente através de um cronjob. Para você ter uma ideia de como funciona  um cron no framework Elgg: http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/CronPlugins
O envio de email é apenas a comunicação de algumas coisas relativas aos usuários do portal, estou tendo cuidado com SPAM.